# Using make, how do I protect against this behavior with .c files in an assembly project?

Tags: makefile, c, gnu-make, assembly

I'm making a super easy NASM x86_64 assembly program `mytest.asm`

```
BITS 64
GLOBAL _start

SECTION .text
    _start:
        mov  rax, 60   ; 'exit' system call
        mov  rdi, 42   ; exit with error code 42
        syscall
```

All this program does is exit with status 42. I made a very simple Makefile for it,

```
AS=nasm
ASFLAGS=-f elf64

.PHONY: all

all: mytest

%.o : %.asm
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"

% : %.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"
```

When executed, this works fine,

```
nasm -f elf64 -o "mytest.o" "mytest.asm"
ld -m elf_x86_64 -o "mytest" "mytest.o"
rm mytest.o
```

Unless there is a file by the same name with `.c`, for example here `mytest.c`

```
// exits with status 66
int main () {
  __asm__ (
    "mov $60, %%rax\n\t"
    "mov $66, %%rdi\n\t"
    "syscall\n\t"
    ::: "%rax", "%rdi"
  );
}
```

If I run `make` with the following file the C code actually gets compiled to `mytest`.

And awkwardly, `$(LDARGS)` gets sent to `$(CC)` and not to `$(LD)`. This seems insecure to me, anyone with this very typical `Makefile` can generate executable from code name by inserting a `.c` file with the same name?

Is this behavior documented by GNU Make?

```
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Ideally, the presence of the `.c` files wouldn't affect the assembly build stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes from [Make’s built-in rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/325233/86440). Make knows how to build executables from C files, so when you ask it to build `mytest` (which is what `make` does since you have an `all` target requiring `mytest`), it builds up its dependency tree and notes that:

- it can build `mytest` from `mytest.c`, following its built-in rule;
- it can build `mytest` from `mytest.o`, following the rule you’ve specified;
- it can build `mytest.o` from `mytest.c`, following its built-in rule;
- it can build `mytest.o` from `mytest.asm`, following the rule you’ve specified.

The first rule wins (I’m not sure what the precedence is), and that’s what it does.

You can disable this using the `-r` option:

```
make -r mytest
```

will always use your rules to build the program.

You can also [cancel built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html#Canceling-Rules) either

- individually by redefining them:

  ```
  % : %.c
  ```

  at the end of your `Makefile` will disable that built-in rule and result in the behaviour you’re after;
- globally by specifying `MAKEFLAGS += -r` in your Makefile.

Comment: Can I state `-r` **inside** the Makefile?

Comment: Actually what I did that worked was `MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules`

Comment: @EvanCarroll: built-in rules are pretty handy a lot of the time.  Also, to avoid name conflicts between object files, it's generally not recommended to have both `foo.asm` and `foo.c`.  It means you can't both `gcc -c foo.c` and `nasm -felf64 foo.asm`.  So it's normal to not do that, and part of why you had to fight against `make` to make it work.

Comment: @PeterCordes I understood this question as being about making a build resilient — how to ensure the correct artifacts are built, even in the presence of unwanted, conflicting artifacts.